# Bash script shell : how to use variable corresponding to filename into nested for loop

Tags: bash, for-loop, awk, sed

I have a large number of directories with their names as :

```
Cl_GG_Omega_m_step_1e-01_der_15
Cl_GG_Omega_m_step_2e-01_der_15
Cl_GG_Omega_m_step_2e-01_der_15
Cl_GG_Omega_m_step_1e-08_der_15
Cl_LL_Omega_m_step_1e-08_der_15
Cl_GL_Omega_m_step_1e-08_der_15
Cl_GG_Omega_m_step_1.1229481712787273e-08_der_15
Cl_LL_Omega_m_step_1.1229481712787273e-08_der_15
Cl_GL_Omega_m_step_1.1229481712787273e-08_der_15
Cl_GG_Omega_m_step_1.2610125953782405e-08_der_15
Cl_LL_Omega_m_step_1.2610125953782405e-08_der_15
```

I would like to get the  directory name (full) whose value appearing between `Òmega_m_step` and `_der_15` is below a cutoff (for example `cutoff=0.01` below) :

For this, I tried to do :

```sh
for i in $(ls --color=never -d Cl_*Omega_m_step_*); do
    for j in $(echo $i); do
        sed 's/.*_step_\([0-9].[0-9]*\)_der_15/\1/g' "$j" | awk -v cutoff=0.01 '{if ($1 < cutoff) print "$j"}'; 
    done;
done
```

The difficulty here is that I would like to get the entire directory name, that's why I used a double `for`loop : the issue is that I don't know to get into nested loop the `$j` directory name (coming from `for j in $(echo $i)`, especially printing it from `awk -v cutoff=0.01 '{if ($1 < cutoff) print "$j"}'` command?

### Update

Thanks for your answers, it helped me a lot. Just a last thing, for the fun, how can I use with `Shell bash` (I mean that I make reference) the outer index $i into nested loop  of a double loop, i.e :

`for i in $(...); do for j in $(...); do "reference to i"; done; done`

Can I do a simple `$i`or `"$i"` ? You will tell me of course that it will depend on the command that uses this index in nested loop. So, even a simple case would be enough for me.

Comment: `echo Cl_*Omega_m_step_* | fmt -1 | awk -F_ '$6<'0.01`

Comment: We only need 4 records to help you solve your problem. One that is below the range you want to print, 2 that are in the range you want to print, and 1 more that is above the range. AND you should then show your required output (and any transformations) of that sample data. Please read about [mcve] and reflect ;-) .  Good luck.

Comment: @jhnc could you epxlain please what does the function `fmt -1` ? Moreover, you don't use the classical `'{print $6}'`printing of field `6` but you use directly the condition (without barackets `{ }`) `'$6<'0.01`.

Comment: Using `ls` might be easier here. `ls Cl_*Omega_m_step_* | awk -F_ '$6<0.01'`.  If running interactively, with alias on ls, start the pipeline with '`ls`

Comment: @dash-o. Thanks. Could you explain me please the difference between `awk -F_ '{if ($6 < 0.01) print $6}'` and your solution `awk -F_ '$6<0.01'` which doesn't require `print` function of awk ? The first seems to keep full directory name ... and what about the function `fmt -1` : I didn't understand well its functionality ? Regards

Comment: I suggest `man fmt` to get information on 'fmt'. Same for `man awk`, they will give you enough information to understand the scrptless. I'll post an answer later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted by the comments, the file name can be broken into '_' separated tokens, including the `step` attribute (6th column). Awk can be used to apply a numeric filter.

```
ls Cl_*Omega_m_step_* | awk -F_ '$6<0.01'
```

Per OP question, clarification for `awk` programs: the following are equivalent.

```
condition 
condition { print }
{ if ( condition ) print }
```

For this example:

```
awk -F_ '$6<0.01'
awk -F_ '$6<0.01 { print }'
awk -F_ '{ if ($6<0.01) print }'
```

Comment: If you do `ls` on directories (as these are), you get their contents. You should probably add `-d`.